# Oracle APEX DML form (with no report) doesn't show existing data in the table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, dml

I've been able to create APEX forms with reports and interactive grids successfully, but when I tried to just create a simple DML form, using the wizard, I get a page where I can create a row, but I can't see the existing data in the table.

This particular table *always* has only one row  and I just need a form to update that 1 row. How can I get this view to open in update mode?

Comment: A quick an easy way to get a page up and running - create a Page, choose Report, Report with Form, Classic Report.  You'll get a Report page and a Form edit page. Fill in the default value for the primary key item on the Form, and delete the report page.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know ahead of time what any of the values in one of the columns, you can use ROWID as the primary key and set it to the row's ROWID in order to trigger the automatic row fetch process.

1. Create a hidden item called `P1_ROWID`. Its **Source** should be set to Database Column, `ROWID`.
2. On the Automatic Row Fetch process, set **Primary Key Column** to `ROWID` and **Primary Key Item** to `P1_ROWID`.
3. Create an additional process, to run *before* the automatic row fetch process, that executes a query like the following:

   ```
   select rowid into :P1_ROWID from mytable;
   ```

[image]

Comment: Both great options.  Thanks!